# Compare the values of 2 columns in pandas dataframe to fill a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (figure). Supose that I will add more observations to my dataframe.

For this new observations (9 and 10) I only add the color, food and age columns. For the score column I want to compare with the other observations if the column of "food" and "color" got the same label then the score value will be equal of that observation.

[image]

In this case the score value is 5.0 and 6.0 respectively. How can I automatize this process when i add a lot of observations without the score value?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

```
import pandas as pd

#Shortened working data list, for demonstration purposes
data = [[1,'Red','Apple',70,5.0],[2,'Yellow','Pizza',90,6.0],[9,'Red','Apple', 2, None],[10,'Yellow','Pizza',2,None]]

#Set up data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Observations', 'Color', 'Food', 'Age', 'Score'])

# Remove nan values
df_cleaned = df[df['Score'].notna()]

#Generate a dictionary with a key that combines Color and Food, and a value that equals Score
targetValues = dict(zip((df_cleaned.Color + df_cleaned.Food), df_cleaned.Score))

#Replace nan values in our original data frame with the values from our dictionary created above
df['Score']=df['Score'].fillna((df.Color + df.Food).map(targetValues))

print(df)
```

That will yield an output like below:

```
   Observations   Color   Food  Age  Score
0             1     Red  Apple   70    5.0
1             2  Yellow  Pizza   90    6.0
2             9     Red  Apple    2    5.0
3            10  Yellow  Pizza    2    6.0
```

The general idea is to create a dictionary, and use those key-value pairs to replace the NaN values in your data frame

Comment: It did not work....